# Cakephp join: retrieving data from two tables

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am working on a Cakephp 2.x.. i have two tables into my db name **Images** and **Audios** .. both have a **userid** field ... first what i want is i want to retrive the data and sort by **date** field which is in both the tables.. on my view page i want to show the images and videos by date...

for example image1,video2,video3,image2

right now i am doing this in Images model

```
   function getImagesAndAudio($userid){
       $this->bindModel(array(
        'belongsTo' => array(
            'Audio' => array(
                'className' => 'Audio',
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions' => array(

                    'Image.user_id = Audio.user_id',




                ),
                'type' => 'LEFT',

                'order'=>'Image.date',//error


            )
        )
    ), false);

    return $this->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Image.User_id' => $userid),
        'contain' => array('Audio' ),
        ));
```

the problem is right now it gives me error if i do this

```
      'order'=>'date',
```

and the other thing i dont know how can i show the images and videos in mixup order... i mean when i do this

```
   foreach ($datas as $data){
     echo $data['Image']['filename'];
     echo $data['Audio']['filename'];

      }
```

the problem is i have to manually write the code that show image now and now show the audio... i want to show the file with respect to date .. so if there is an image after the two audios file show an image and then so on

Comment: Shouldn't order be - `'order'=> array('Image.date') ` ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct i think this approach should work:

Define the proper Relations between Image/Audio and User (User hasMany Audio/Image and Audio/Image belongsTo User)

You can define how the related Images/Audio Files should be ordered (see CakePHP Documentation: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany)

Now in your controller just set the user for your view and you can retrieve your data with

```
<?php
//Same goes for Image
foreach($userVariable[‘Audio‘] as $audio) {
    echo $audio['filename‘]
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation.  {With little success, I tried using CakePHP's Hash class to merge the two models' arrays in order to combine the models into a single recordset.  Maybe another person can chime in and explain how to do this with just CakePHP.}

What worked for me, was to consolidate the two models (tables) within my MySQL database through a view.  Continue to use your existing models for Image and Audio CrUD operations.  For this page, use a new model based on a view.  Here is example view code:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_combined_audio_images AS
SELECT user_id, created, modified, foo, null as bar, 'image' as type
FROM images
UNION
SELECT user_id, created, modified, null, bar, 'audio'
FROM audio;
```

For me, I needed fields that were in one table and not the other.  In the code example, you can see that the images table has "foo" which is not in audio and audio has "bar" not in images. (Just be careful of data type casting.)  I also used a field to determine which type of record it was (see "type" above.)

Then create the model

```
class Asset extends AppModel{
public $useTable = 'vw_combined_audio_images';
public $belongsTo = array('User' => array(####));
}
```

Then add the model to the $hasMany array of the User model